# iphone - Its quiet confusing with using blocks to get sub array from array

Tags: iphone, json, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

I'm having an array of objects (json objects)
each object is of following nature:

```
{
        author = "<null>";
        category =         {
            "created_at" = "2011-02-06T18:11:39Z";
            id = 4;
            name = lawyers;
        };
        "created_at" = "<null>";
        id = 693;
        "mobile_user_id" = "<null>";
        "rating_count" = 0;
        status = 1;
        text = "A brain walks into a bar and says, \"I'll have a pint of beer please. \"The barman looks at him and says \"Sorry, I can't serve you.\" \"Why not?\" asks the brain. \"You're already out of your head.\"";
        title = "A brain goes to a local bar";
    }
```

From those array of objects, I want to find objects whose category has id = 4 and make a sub array.

Can some one help me in using blocks and get sub array from array please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess by "using blocks", you mean using a method of NSArray like

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

Then it would look like

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [yourArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return (BOOL)([[obj valueForKeyPath:@"category.id"] intValue] == 4);
}];
NSArray *filteredArray = [yourArray objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

That's for what you asked, but I'd rather use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.id = %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
NSArray *filteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: Some blogs says that use blocks rather using predicate. Why do you want to use "predicate" to get sub array? And your block code is throwing error "Invalid conversion initializing integer 'int', expected block pointer", is there anything wrong with my json data?

Comment: My projects use a target OS < 4.0, so I can't use blocks for that.

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid conversion initializing integer 'int', expected block pointer", what's wrong with our comparision?

Comment: I've been a bit quick when I wrote the block... I edited the answer.